# Convert a data.table to list of rows that are data.tables and apply a function to each row

Tags: r, list, data.table, apply, rows

Let's say, I have a data.table in R. I want to convert it to a list in which each element is a separate data.table that contains only one row. I then have a function that is applied to each one-row datatable. I want to rbind the output.

I have tried many versions of the apply family, but cant get it to work.

I want to do the following but using apply functions as my real data.tables are very big and there are many of them. Also, the actual function is much more complicated.

```r
DT <- data.table(
  ID = c("b","a","c"),
  a = 1:3,
  b = 7:9,
  c = 13:15
)

DT1<-DT[1]
DT2<-DT[2]
DT3<-DT[3]

list<-list(DT1, DT2, DT3)

myfunction<-function(D){
  return(rbind(D, D))
}

DT1new<-myfunction(list[[1]])
DT2new<-myfunction(list[[2]])
DT3new<-myfunction(list[[3]])

result<-rbind(DT1new, DT2new, DT3new)
result
```

Comment: What is the application? What is the end result you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question a bit. It should be clear now!

Comment: Do you need `DT[rep(1:nrow(DT), each = 2)]` same as `DT[DT[, rep(.I, each = 2)]]` ?

Comment: The actual function is much more than repeating rows. And it only takes one row data.tables.

Comment: @maja I am still confident you can bypass that first step but can't give detailed clues without further info.

Comment: Thank you and I am sorry this is so confusing. How about now?

Comment: @maja see updated answer. Is this enough of clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for you first wish: convert a data.table to a list of many where each table is one row in the original table:

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(DT)), function(i) DT[i])
# or
split(DT, seq_len(nrow(DT)))
```

And judging by the current description on the application (repeat each of the current rows) you can bypass this first step with:

```
DT[rep(seq_len(.N), each = 2)]
# or 
DT[, .SD[c(1,1)], by = seq_len(nrow(DT))]
```

And more generally you should be able to do (to operate on one row at a time):

```
DT[, myFunction(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(DT))]
```